# Jquery Bind and Unbind Events to a Selector on Click of Button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, bind, unbind

I have the following HTML and JS. The Controls are disabled when the page loads.
I need to enable the controls when the user clicks the Enable Button and when the user clicks the Disable Button the Conrols needs to disabled again.

```
<div id="main" >
    <input type="text" id="Year" name="Year" class="mytextbox disabled"  />
    <br />
    <input type="text" id="StudentID" name="StudentID"  class="mytextbox disabled" />
    <br />
    <br />
    <input type="button" id="enableButton" name="enableButton" value="Enable" />
    <br />
    <br />    
    <input type="button" id="disableButton" name="disableButton" value="Disable" />
</div>

$(".disabled").keydown(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault ? e.preventDefault() : e.returnValue = false;
});

$(".disabled").bind("copy paste cut", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault ? e.preventDefault() : e.returnValue = false;
});

$("#enableButton").click(function (e) {
    $(".mytextbox").removeClass("disabled");
});

$("#disableButton").click(function (e) {
    $(".mytextbox").addClass("disabled");
});
```

Comment: simply `if($(this).hasClass('disbaled') { do nothing; e.preventDefault(); e.stopImmediatePropagtion(); }`

Comment: where should i add this code.....

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/eSsmV/

Comment: Omar.. That worked..... but I have a question, is there any way to bind and unbind the events (keydown, copy, cut and paste) to .mytextbox selectors on the respective button click.

Comment: you can do this `$("#enableButton").click(function (e) { $(".mytextbox").removeClass("disabled"); $(".mytextbox").unbind("copy paste cut keydown"); });`

Comment: I have done the unbind part... but i am unable to do bind the events back when the user clicks the disabled button again.